# Textbox format not accepting to type numbers with points

Tags: c#

I am using this code to type the currency amounts in a textbox with comma seperators and points. While typing numbers should display like this format(1,258,891.50). My code is working bt I can't type points. Its accepting only full numbers. Below is my code....

```
if (textBox5.Text == "")
    return;

int n = textBox5.SelectionStart;
decimal text = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox5.Text);
textBox5.Text = String.Format("{0:#,###0}", text);
textBox5.SelectionStart = n + 1;
```

Comment: what is "textBox5"? what platform are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `CurrentCulture` has *already* `,` as a [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) and `.` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx), you can use [The (`"N"`) format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#NFormatString) as `N2` like;

```
textBox5.Text = text.ToString("N2");
```

If it is not, you can [`Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) your `CurrentCulture`, set these values to your properties and use *that* culture as a second parameter in `ToString` method.

```
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
textBox5.Text = text.ToString("N2", clone); // 1,258,891.50
```

Comment: its not giving the correct order while typing its only showing comma seperators and points.

Comment: @MohamedShakir What do you mean by _correct order_ exactly? Order or what? Your `text` isn't `1258891.50` as a `decimal`? Have you _ever_ tried my second code example?

Comment: I have tried with your second code, bt its not displaying in an order it means if we type a number like (1500) it shows like this 5100).

Comment: this is how i used ur code 
if (textBox5.Text == "")
                return;
            Decimal text = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox5.Text);
            textBox5.Text = text.ToString("N2");
            var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            clone.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
            clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            textBox5.Text = text.ToString("N2", clone);

while typing (1500) it shows like (5,001.00)

Comment: Gonul I already used your code on textbox textchanged event, now i tried with keypress event its working anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your string format `"{0:#,###0}"` is not specifying any decimal places, so it is converting it without any decimal places. (Also the `0` at the end is actually doing nothing.)

Try this instead:

```
textBox5.Text = String.Format("{0:#,###.##}", text);
```

If for some reason you really do want to force a `0` at the end, try this:

```
textBox5.Text = String.Format("{0:#,###.#\\0}", text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox5.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(textBox5.Text));
```